# Slow Transaction#success() after a single change to the DB

Tags: java, neo4j

First of all, I have a server with an SSD and 32GB of RAM, so I don't consider hardware as a bottleneck.

The problem is, I have a tree-simulating structure where each node has 2 relationships (to its parent and child):

```
 _               _
/1\-CHILD_OF--->/2\
\_/<-PARENT_OF->\_/
```

That is, node #1 is a child of node 2 and node #2 is a parent of #1 (I do know that is excessive and one relationship should be enough, but I'm just playing around for now.

So, I have this procedure, "change the parent of a subtree", i.e., given `node` and `new_parent`, I should do the following: remove `node`'s relationship with its parent and create a new towards it parent. As you see, this is not a big deal. However, when I call `transaction.success()` after that, the pause seems to be *really significant* (>20 seconds). The size of the DB is 29 GB (115*10^6 nodes.

How can I get rid of that slowdown?

Edit (code sample):
Usage:

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("/ssd/" + "neotree");
changeNodeParent(positivePseudoRandomLong(rng, 120000000), positivePseudoRandomLong(rng, 120000000));
```

Where

```
private static void changeNodeParent(long eid, long pid) {
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        Node nodeInDistress = graphDb.getNodeById(eid);
        Node newFoundParent = graphDb.getNodeById(pid);

        // remove eid-pid relationship
        nodeInDistress.getSingleRelationship(Hier.PARENT_OF, Direction.INCOMING).delete();
        newFoundParent.createRelationshipTo(nodeInDistress, Hier.PARENT_OF);

        // place new relationship
        nodeInDistress.createRelationshipTo(newFoundParent, Hier.CHILD_OF);

        tx.success();
        }
    }
```

*UPD*

I was running some tests concerning standalone server performance. I had 2 basic cases for testing read and write characteristics, both formulated as POST requests.

So, the reading is predictably fast when testing with Apache `ab` from the remote host (3-node setup was used), and increasing amount of concurrent connections doesn't seem to drop the performance (even increase it) (tested with levels 1, 10, ..., 100).

But the writing tests seem to suffer greatly from the concurrent writes, and I think again due to transaction overhead. What I basically tried is tinkering with `org.neo4j.server.transaction.timeout` and `org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads`. The thing is if I leave them default and perform tests with concurrency level set to 100 (i.e. 100 simultaneous requests to server), nearly 30% of all the requests fail (return code is not that of success according to `ab`). If I increase `transaction.timeout`, the amount of failed requests decreases (the concurrency level doesn't seem to affect the value in a significant way). Basically, if I set timeout to 1 minute, only 10% of requests are failed and so on. That leads me to a conclusion of some transaction bottleneck again. I redesigned the database so the only relationships are only `CHILD_OF` (that decreased `relationship_store` size twice), but it doesn't seem to affect the aforementioned problem. Each node has exactly one `CHILD_OF` relationship (except for the root), but one node can be the `endNode` of more than one such relationship (1 to 100 approximately).

Comment: please share a code snippet.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, is my update comprehensive or should I add something else?

Comment: This is really weird, what version of Neo4j are you using? Can you post your "/ssd/neotree/messages.log" somewhere for checking some settings? This should be a nano/millisecond operation. Any chance to attach a profiler to your app and check for hotspots? Also how many CHILD_OF rels do your nodes usually have?

Comment: @MichaelHunger, please see my update in the question.